# Define a property as string or function that returns a string in Typescript

Tags: typescript, declaration, tsd

I want to create an interface where a property can be either a `string` or a `Function` that has to return a `string`. I currently have the following:

```
interface IExample {
  prop: string|Function;
}
```

But that's not explicit enough for me because the `Function` is allowed to return anything. I want to tell the compiler that the return value has to be a `string`.

How is this possible in TypeScript? Or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
type propType = () => string;

interface IExample {
   field : string | propType;
}

class MyClass1 implements IExample {
    field : string;
}

class MyClass2 implements IExample {
    field() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

#### Update 1

```
type PropertyFunction<T> = () => T;

interface IExample {
   field : string | PropertyFunction<string>;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Side note: If someone ones a more specialied version, you can also do something like `type StringFunction = () => string;`